# How do I create pairlist with empty elements in R?

Tags: r, tree, substitution

In R, when I do

```
substitute(function(a) { a })[[2]]
```

I see the following pairlist:

```
$a
```

Note that the value of the element is empty. How can I create such a pairlist? The following doesn't work for me :

```
> pairlist(a="")
$a
[1] ""
```

I am asking this in the context of programmatically creating a function. I want to do something like

```
> call("function", pairlist(a=""), call("{", as.symbol("a")))
function(a = "") {
    a
}
```

This is quite close to what I get by doing

```
> substitute(function(a){a})
function(a) {
    a
}
```

except for the function argument part.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
> as.pairlist(alist(a=))
$a
```

maybe what you want to do is:

```
> f2 <- as.function(alist(a=1,b=,{a+b}))
> f2
function (a = 1, b) 
{
    a + b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `alist(a=)`.

You may also find the functions `formals` and `body` helpful in programatically creating a function, rather than `substitute` and `call`.  Here's an example from the documentation `?formals`

```
f <- function(x) a+b
formals(f) <- alist(a=,b=3) # function(a,b=3)a+b
f(2) # result = 5
```

which could be extended like this

```
body(f) <- expression(2*a+b)
f(2) # result = 7
```